# Code written on Android Studio 2.1.1 won't work on Android Studio 2.2.3 and the weird thing is it won't generate any errors too

Tags: android

I have made an wifi app that scans for available networks and connect to specific network. I used the Android Studio version 2.1.1 but the same code does not work on Android Studio version 2.2.3 and it won't give any errors. I have search a lot but could not be able to find a solution. Please help

Below are the methods that won't work.

```
public int connectToWifi(String networkSSID, String networkPasskey) {
    for (ScanResult result : wifiList) {
        if (result.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {

            String securityMode = getScanResultSecurity(result);

            WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = createAPConfiguration(networkSSID, networkPasskey, securityMode);

            int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
            Log.d(TAG, "# addNetwork returned " + res);

            wifiManager.disconnect();

            boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

            wifiManager.reconnect();

            boolean changeHappen = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

            if (res != -1 && changeHappen) {
                registerReceiver(new WifiReciever(),
                        new IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
                Log.d(TAG, "# Change happen");


            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wrong Password");
            }

            return res;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
private WifiConfiguration createAPConfiguration(String networkSSID, String networkPasskey, String securityMode) {
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

    wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";

    if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN")) {

        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("WEP")) {

        wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPasskey + "\"";
        wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

    } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("PSK")) {


        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPasskey + "\"";

        wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
        wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);


    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "# Unsupported security mode: " + securityMode);
        return null;
    }

    return wifiConfiguration;

}
public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {

    final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
    final String[] securityModes = {"WEP", "PSK", "EAP"};

    for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
            return securityModes[i];
        }
    }

    return "OPEN";
}
```

`

Comment: Android Studio is just an IDE. It shouldn't impact your code. You probably did something else... Could you post your code? The app crashes? Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing it?

Comment: the app won't crashes and yes i re-installed app various times

Comment: Use the debugger, set some break points. Or work on a [mcve]